# convex hull of three orthogonal line segments

Tags: computational-geometry, convex-hull, line-segment

I got three line segments in 3D. They are pairwise orthogonal but they don't need to touch. If they touch, the volume of the convex hull of them is 1/6*s1*s2*s3 where s1,s2,s3 are the lengths of the line segments. This can be easily computed. But what happens if they don't touch? I expect that the convex hull doesn't get smaller.

I would be grateful if anyone have an idea how to proof that or could give a counter example.

Comment: If I can place the segments arbitrarily far from each other, the volume can get arbitrarily large, even for fix segment sizes. Or maybe I didn't get your problem...

Comment: You do get it right, but what I need is a lower bound for the volume. Sorry for being not precise enough.

Comment: This is more of a mathematics problem than programming problem.  Please consider asking this on Mathematics Stack Exchange: http://math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Lemma 6 from http://cms.math.ca/openaccess/cjm/v3/cjm1951v03.0054-0061.pdf gives the desired result. If we choose P and Q to be the endpoints of the longest line segments, then the projection in two dimensions contains the other line segments that are still orthogonal.